# Workbook level events not firing in my .xlam

Tags: vba, events, add-in, xlsm

I have a simple .xlsm as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  MsgBox "Workbook open"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox "Sheet Change"
End Sub
```

This works as an .xlsm file. However, when I convert this to an .xlsm and register it with the add-ins, these events no longer fire. Does anyone know why that might be?

Comment: But, the rest of the .xlam code does work?

Comment: Please check the add-in Properties, in General Tab if in the down right corner there is a check  box 'Unblock'. It happens when the add-in comes by mail or it is downloaded from internet. Besides that, it is good to introduce its path folder to the Trusted Locations.

Comment: `Workbook_SheetChange` will only fire if your add-in modifies a sheet in `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the add-in "workbook" itself). Presumably you're looking for `Application`-level events, so your `Workbook_Open` handler should assign a module-level `Private WithEvents App As Excel.Application` private field, and then you'd be able to handle `App_Xxxxxxx` events.

Comment: Similarly, `Workbook_Open` will fire when *the add-in* is loaded. If you mean to pop a `MsgBox` whenever *any* workbook opens, you need to handle application-level events.

Comment: Do you programmatically make changes to the add-in sheets?

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the replies. Yes, this requires an app level event handler. I am posting the working code below. Also note that there was a macro trust issue when the .xlam was first created. Watch out for that. Trust Center => Add-ins had a check box on "Require application add-ins to be signed by a trusted publisher." Turning that off (for development) got things rolling. Normally that would stay checked and you would sign the .xlam with a digital certificate and trust that publisher.

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
    App.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "std workbook open"
End Sub

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "app new workbook"
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "app Sheet change"
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox "app workbook Open"
End Sub
```